# typecast to (void *) when passing pointer to object

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, void-pointers

Consider the following snippet:

```
void my_func(int a, void *b);
...

struct my_struct s = { };
my_func(10, (void *)&s);
```

Is it necessary to typecast to `(void *)` when passing `&s` to the function?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. Any object pointer can be silently converted back and forth to and from `void*`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Perhaps not always silently. `void my_func(int a, void *b);
int main(void) {
  const char *x;
  my_func(1,x);
}` --> "warning: passing argument 2 of 'my_func' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]"  Yet agree in this case, no cast needed.

Comment: Specially when gcc flag `-pendantic` is used .  Compilation command: `gcc -Wall -pendantic main.c -o main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not have to with some exceptions as you may get the warning if the object which reference you pass to the function is `volatile` or `const` - generally has different attribute.

```
void ee(void *q)
{
    pritntf("%p", q);
}

volatile int g;
const int f;

int main()
{

    ee(&g);
    ee(&f);
}
```

gives this warnings:

```
<source>: In function 'main':

<source>:17:8: warning: passing argument 1 of 'ee' discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

     ee(&g);

        ^~

<source>:6:15: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'volatile int *'

 void ee(void *q)

         ~~~~~~^

<source>:18:8: warning: passing argument 1 of 'ee' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

     ee(&f);

        ^~

<source>:6:15: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'const int *'

 void ee(void *q)

         ~~~~~~^

Compiler returned: 0
```

Answer (score 5):

A pointer to any type may be freely converted to or from a `void *` without a cast.

Section 6.3.2.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type.  A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a 
>   pointer  to void and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.

The only time a cast is needed is if you pass a pointer to a variadic function like `printf` where an implicit conversion can't occur, since it won't know what the exact type being passed in is.

Note that, as with any pointer type, you can't "remove" a qualifier such as `const` when passing to a function without a cast.  Sections 6.3.2.3p2 states:

> For any  qualifier *q*, a pointer  to  a  non-*q*-qualified  type  may  be  converted  to  a  pointer  to the *q*-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal.

Comment: the is no conversion on any modern system (except the 8 bits systems with named address spaces or far pointers). The times of the

Comment: @P__J__ "Conversion" is not a system specific thing, but a term that the standard is using.

Comment: IMO it is wrong - the word cast should be used. Conversion and cast mean something different.

Comment: Casting is the operation which is performing conversion - *Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast.* - http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4p5.

Comment: @P__J__ Referencing your answer, that has nothing to do with `void *` and everything to do with qualifiers.  You'll get the same if you pass a `const int *` when a `int *` is expected.

Comment: Yes - but from the practical point of view,, it does not matter. It is considered a good practice (and most companies do) to treat warnings as errors. So if someone will follow your advice - the code want compile.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not required, it just makes the code clearer on what exactly is being passed to the function.

Comment: No warnings should be ever produced without the cast.